# Oracle get column in zipped format

Tags: oracle, select, compression, clob

I have a table which stores topology and size of topology is huge. It is stored  in CLOB format.

My problem here is, can I get this CLOB in compressed format. As my application server receives large number of requests to get this topology data over REST call, and sometimes it goes Out Of Memory.

Is there any procedure which can compress column on the fly, like

```
SELECT ZIPPED ( TOPOLOGY ), TOPOLOGY_ID, INSERTED_DATE FROM DAILY_TOPOLOGY WHERE ...
```

In my scenario, I can't save this data in compressed format, as DB is shared and data is not owned by us. We have only read access to it.

Comment: There is no Oracle built-in function. However, Anton Scheffer has published a PL/SQL package which you can use. [Find it here](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/as_zip8.txt)

Comment: Look up the `UTL_COMPRESS` Oracle PLSQL package as a starting point.

Comment: If the gzip format suits you, you can use [utl_compress.lz_compress](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_compr.htm#ARPLS70831).

Comment: @TenG - documentation says that `utl_compress.lz_compress()` works [with BLOB, RAW and BFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_compr.htm#ARPLS70838).  The OP has data in a CLOB.

Comment: Sorry. For CLOBs, `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW + UTL_COMPRESS`.

Comment: Do you know that this data will compress well? If you wind up going to a lot of work compressing the data to save 5% space, it may not be worth it. All compression algorithms are going to work with `BLOBs`, not `CLOBs`, so you're also going to need to convert it.